# Minutes of meeting module for drupal 7

Tags: 7

I have a new requirement. I need a minutes of meeting module. I.e. after each meeting i.e. weekly they will add action items and assign it to some user and as soon as the user logs in, it should be shown to him. So is there any existing module which is even close to this. I don't mind sitting and customizing the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a custom *Action Items* content type and then [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to handle the scheduling and assignments.  Rules and fields (via content types) should be flexible enough to handle such a workflow and they have the further advantage of being well-supported and documented.

Comment: so there is no exiting module or distribution for this.

Comment: It really depends on the specifics of your use case, but you didn't provide many details.  However, as far as I know there is no general "turn minutes into action items" module-- different organizations would want to implement such workflows in completely different ways, so it would be very difficult to develop a standard solution.  But with a custom content type, Rules, and Views you should be able to do everything you want.

Comment: I agree with Patrick.   You should use create a new content type and use the rules module.   You may also want to use the Flag module to flag it on or off if the user has read it.  No there is no module that does this already.  Atleast to my knowledge.